# How to update/append a string with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to check whether in `querystring` there is something like `[?|&]rid=\d`,

if there is,I want to update the `\d` with a specific `rid_value`,

else I want to append `&rid=rid_value` to `querystring`

Comment: I agree with Pointy.  Show some love!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pattern = /rid=\d/;
if(pattern.test(querystring)){
    querystring = querystring.replace(/rid=\d/, 'rid=' + rid_value);
} else{
    querystring = querystring + '&rid=' + rid_value;
}
```